# Use power query to split csv file not multiple tables

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have used power query in the past, but am not an expert. I have a fold of logs that I want to import into PBI to create a dashboard. The log files have multiple tables on one sheet. (see folder in link).

How can I combine all sheets and then split them into 4 tables? The headings in all files are the same and can be found in the first column. They are: Report Generated, Panelist Details, Attendee Details, Other Attended.

[Sample files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19KcLeM44MVaNq5MP0bGQzUujwid7c3Km?usp=sharing)

Comment: That looked like live data which is crazy to post here, but it is up to you

Comment: @horseyride thank you for your comment. I meant to upload a folder of anonymised data but posted the wrong one. I have updated the to the correct data set. I am fairly new to this forum, is it incorrect to post data sets here?

Comment: Data sets are fine; it just seemed odd you would want real data in there including emails, etc

Comment: Yes, I understand. You are absolutely correct, this was my mistake. Thanks for your feedback. The update files have fake names and email addresses.

Comment: There's no source files so all we can see is the cached results, the query steps can't be tested. -- If you have multiple tables with the same columns, in one query -- you can make a step that is `Table1 & Table2` and it will combine them. If you want to generate 4 tables, make the base query, set it to `do not update` then `reference query`, and drill down to the first table. do the same for the other 3.